# Echo Color Style

Tags: php, css

I'm setting a table that it gets information from a MySQL table. I want to change the inside row text color. How can I show the text inside the table in white color?

I tried to add `<style = color #34242`, but it didn't work correctly.

```
echo '<span class="info-detail">' . "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>"  . $row["price"] .  "<td> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-trans waves-effect waves-primary w-md m-b-5\" data-selly-product=\"$row[selly]\" >Buy Now</button></td>" . "</td></tr>" ;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you added the style. Also, it seems that a `<span>` directly before a `<tr>` will produce invalid HTML. I suggest adding a class to the table or to a particular row or cell, depending on what you want to style. Then define that class with white text color in a stylesheet. It might help to show more of your code for context and let us know which text you want to style as white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this inside your `<body>`

```
<style>
.info-detail{
color: #fff;
}
</style>
```